# error keyword in .NET languages

Tags: .net, fxcop

Which .NET languages have `error` as a keyword?

I have a class named `Error` and FxCop says it's a reserved language keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a reserved word in VB.Net

```
On Error Resume Next
```

It's a case insensitive language so even lower case usages of it are ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Likely its the carry over from classic VB and brought into VB.NET.